# Can't print $base_root in headers view

Tags: views

I have a View and inside it I have and Attachment display. In this attachment I set a Header with the value you can see in the image below.
I'm sure I have register_globals = 1;
But nothing is printed...
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is more a PHP question than a Drupal question; using a global variable in code executed from `eval()` or a function always require to define the variable as global, or using `$GLOBALS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to say that what you want to display is global as well:

```
<?php
global $base_root;
print $base_root;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my first project with Drupal and the first time I use globals vars.

Comment: As alternative, use `$GLOBALS['base_root']`.